# Django, twitter and its new API

Tags: django, twitter

I need to retrieve tweets from certain users. I have found 2 packages which seem promising, however there was an recent Twitter API update to 1.1, so I am not sure will below options work properly. Anybody has any experience with python-twitter and ECL-twitter after API update?

http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/

https://github.com/elmcitylabs/ECL-Twitter

Or would you recommend me something else?
As I said, I need to retrieve tweets from certain users, who do not have to be in my friend list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with python-twitter to retrieve tweets from certain users on multiple sites. Since you don't need to be logged in for that, there is no problem at all.

Comment: +1 confirmed without login, retrieving text, username or data is no problem. Regarding oauth - does it work with python-twitter now? Thank you very much for reply.

Comment: I would advise you to start a new topic. I did some tests with oauth, but that is more then a year ago, so I cannot advise you on this.